# Dynamically change table data based on the order of another table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

New to mysql and need some help big time! I have 2 tables - table A and table B which are set up like this:

Table A - `event`.

```
Event   | Date       |  Time
=====
1       | 2014-07-06 | 9am
2       | 2014-08-08 | 10am
3       | 2014-10-10 | 10am
```

Table B - `location`

```
Event   | Date       |  Description | Directions*
=====
1       | 2014-08-08 | Grand Canyon | bar
2       | 2014-10-06 | Devils Tower | foo
3       | 2014-07-06 | Pacific Park | foo
3       | 2014-07-06 | Universal Studios | foo
```

Now the trouble I'm having is how to properly re-order or swap values in table B - locations. according to table A -event. How do I update the locations table to change properly as well?

Basically i need to find all previous event values and update them with the new event values.

This is the outcome of table B - location that i would like to see when table A-event is changed.

Table B - `location`

```
Event | Date         |  Description | Directions
=====
1       | 2014-07-06 | Pacific Park | foo
1       | 2014-07-06 | Universal Studios | foo
2       | 2014-08-08 | Grand Canyon | bar
3       | 2014-10-06 | Devils Tower | foo
```

I forgot to mention that I will need to be able to loop through and find all instances.  as well

Comment: please don't store date and time separately

Comment: ok I'll make that change to my database, thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing the date in 2 separate tables?

Comment: I guess I don't need to store the date twice I'll make that change to my database as well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the InnoDB storage engine, you can specify an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` rule on a foreign key constraint definition:

```
ALTER TABLE `location`
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_location_event (event) REFERENCES event (event)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Then (as long as FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is not disabled in the session), when you issue an UPDATE statement to change the value of the the `event` column in the `event` table, related rows in the `location` table will also be modified.

For example, if you issue this statement:

```
UPDATE `event` SET `event` = 4 WHERE `event` = 1;
```

It would be roughly equivalent to performing these two statements:

```
UPDATE `event` SET `event` = 4 WHERE `event` = 1;
UPDATE `location` SET `event` = 4 WHERE `event` = 1;
```

Comment: Spencer. Thanks for the quick response i didn't know how fast things work on this board.  I'm attempting to do this now but I'm curious as to how I would i be able to get the previous value just in case other events were moved.  Ie meaning im not 100% sure which event wants to be moved around. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: With a foreign key constraint, the 'relationship' between the rows will be maintained. Once the update is completed, there's no way to "get" the previous value. But it's not clear why you would need that. You wouldn't be able to 'swap' the `event` values without using a third placeholder and a series of three updates, 1=>foo, 3=>1, foo=>3.

Comment: hmmm....I think i see what you are saying, which means this should work. So i guess my problem that i can't wrap my head around would be how to loop through the update to check the where clauses. I'e SET `event` = 4 WHERE `event` = 1, SET `event` = 2 WHERE `event` = 3, SET `event` = 1 WHERE `event` = 1; Just in case more changes have been make to event table.  Hope that makes sense.  And Spencer your patience with me is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Jim Brown: we typically avoid this type of problem by _not_ changing the unique key of a row. Using an extra placeholder is a common approach; e.g. if you want to "swap" the values of two variables `a` and `b`... `foo := a; a := b; b := foo;`. The question that hasn't been asked is why it's necessary to "swap" the values at all.

Comment: Spencer. I felt it was necessary to do (but I could be wrong) because, I wanted this system to allow the user to drag and drop/reorder and catalog their trip events for example. if the user initially input into the system that they planed on going to Walt disney World, SeaWorld Orlando and Epcot center in that order. But the stopped at a local park, that was not originally on the schedule. The uploaded, all their pictures, got home and said oh yeah we went to the park first on our trip. We need to rearrange our pictures, and directions to go with the event.

Comment: cont...I would like them to just be able to rearrange their event table and the location table will update accordingly. So I guess i will need a placeholder column as well.  Hope that makes more sense and again thanks for your patience

Comment: Spencer. Any thoughts. Anyone have any thoughts

Comment: @Jim Brown: based on your description of the use case, I would tend to include another column for "sequencing"; that's my fallback for something like this (a specific ordering items which isn't by id or some other attribute). If it's not datetime related, then I typically add a simple integer column name `seq_`, and assign values to that. The values don't have to be contiguous, just ordered. And the values only have to appear in the one table, it's not necessary to repeat them in the child table, we can pick them up with a JOIN if we need them.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest moving the date and time into table B, in case the event happens in 2 different locations at 2 different times... right now your data implies that the event can happen at multiple places, but they must happen at the same date and time.

anyways, to answer your question in case you are dealing with legacy tables (and you ahve no control over the schema), you could do it via the UI Controller code, or you could create a mysql trigger on Table A that would update Table B Dates...

if you're asking about existing data...
you could do an update statement joining by 'Date' column:
`UPDATE location b 
    JOIN event a 
      ON b.Date = a.Date
SET b.Event= a.Event`

that statement will update your 'location' table with the 'Event' id from your 'event' table, where the Date fields match